# Optimize json transfer from server to client

Tags: json, performance, server, client, transfer

**SCENARIO:**

A query returns 100,000 records which are sent to a client in JSON format.

**The record structure is:**

```
ID  
FirstName  
LastName  
Address  
TelephoneNumber
```

The target object on the client has the same structure, so:

```
ID  
FirstName  
LastName  
Address  
TelephoneNumber
```

The data transfer in JSON format will contain the field definitions with their name in string format, so:

```
[  
{"ID":1,"FirstName":"pippo","LastName":"pippo_ln","Address":"via vatte la pesca","TelephoneNumber":"12345"},
{"ID":1,"FirstName":"pippo","LastName":"pippo_ln","Address":"via vatte la pesca","TelephoneNumber":"12345"},
{"ID":1,"FirstName":"pippo","LastName":"pippo_ln","Address":"via vatte la pesca","TelephoneNumber":"12345"},
---
100,000 records
---
]
```

**REQUEST:**

Is it possible to reduce automatically the JSON string to a minimum to speed up the transfer and rebuild it by mapping the fields in the same order?

So, the new JSON format is:

```
[
{"a":1,"b":"pippo","c":"pippo_ln","d":"via vatte la pesca","e":"12345"},
{"a":1,"b":"pippo","c":"pippo_ln","d":"via vatte la pesca","e":"12345"},
{"a":1,"b":"pippo","c":"pippo_ln","d":"via vatte la pesca","e":"12345"},
---
100,000 records
---
]
```

and the mapping the fields in:

```
a => ID
b => FirstName
c => LastName
d => Address
e => TelephoneNumber
```

and recreate object list on destination client?

Tnx

PS:
Enabling compression on the client may be a workaround, but I would really like to minimize the original string as well ... which will definitely be compressed.

Comment: Please clarify the question

Comment: You have to ask the dev who wrote the server-side script if you'd like to have shorter json property names. On client side you can enable compression though (example in PowerShell): `Invoke-WebRequest www.google.com -Headers @{'Accept-Encoding'='gzip'}`. In this case length of property names shouldn't matter anymore as gzip could easily compress this kind of redundant data.

Comment: Enabling compression on the client may be a workaround, but I would really like to minimize the original string as well ... which will definitely be compressed.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the depth of each record is only 1, so you could use CSV instead of JSON. Doing so, you won't have to transmit the keys of your object for each record.

Something like the following (with headers) :

```
ID,Firstname,Lastname,Address,TelephoneNumber
1,pippo,pippo_ln,via vatte la pesca,12345
1,pippo,pippo_ln,via vatte la pesca,12345
1,pippo,pippo_ln,via vatte la pesca,12345
```

Also, the first thing to do would be to enable compression. The most efficient one nowadays would be Brotli, so just add the following header to your request :

```
Content-Encoding: br, gzip
```

This way, it will fallback to `gzip` if Brotli compression is not implemented on the server side.

Also, when dealing with big amounts of data, I would recommend implementing pagination